# when does a client timeout starts?

Tags: iis, wsdl, tcpclient, dotnet-httpclient

Okay here is the scenario:

Clients send a request at 10:00:00 (H:M:S). That request is stored in the IIS app pool QUEUE until there is an available thread for that request. Thread is released and the app pool now received the request that it has to process. The time is 10:00:15.

When did the client start waiting for his response - at 10:00:00 or 10:00:15?

Answer (score 1):

Client timeout period started at 10:00:00. The client has no idea what's going on with the internals of the server, nor even network latency. All it knows is when the request was sent and when a response was received (if at all).

While there may be more granular timeouts at the [platform-specific message handler level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.winhttphandler) (`SendTimeout`, `ReceiveHeadersTimeout`, `ReceiveDataTimeout`), the `Timeout` defined on .NET Standard-compliant implementations of `HttpClient` is end-to-end. Per [Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2857#issuecomment-132252056):

> The HttpClient.Timeout property is intended to be exactly what you are
>   referring to as the 99% case: an end-to-end timeout after which the
>   request expires. The WinHttpHandler API is intended to provide a
>   deeper control to developers for more advanced scenarios. In keeping
>   with this intention, we have more granular timeouts on that type since
>   we have gotten developer requests in the past who asked for control
>   over a specific stage of the request.

Comment: are you sure there is no http or tcp handshake that confirms a request is now being processed? Your answer is not very descriptive. I want to know what happens on connection level

Comment: Sorry, I figured you wanted the quick answer. Details added.

Comment: @vLr Does this still not answer your question? Not sure what else you're looking for here.